# Нет перевода описания для "Выглядит нормально" в запоздалых ответах

Tags: предложение, локализация, очередь-проверок

Не переведена фраза в [Очереди проверок > Запоздалые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) (Открывается на 500+ репутации).

[image: 1]

Предлагаю в кандидаты мой перевод: **Ответ на заданный вопрос, уникальный и не является низкокачественным.**

Comment: В начале смысл не  `заданный`, а `относится/касается/адресован`. Т.е. ответ именно на поставленный вопрос, а не на что-то левое, например на комментарий

Comment: @EzioMercer да я в начале так и написал "адресованный", но позже изменил на "на заданный" т.к. подумал что что-то неправильно написал.

Comment: Начало бы я перевел как "Отвечает на вопрос". "Является" лучше переформулировать, это канцеляриат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил следующий вариант перевода:

> Answer addresses the question, is unique, and is not low quality.
> Отвечает на заданный вопрос и не является низкокачественным или дубликатом.
>
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16757

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.