# Не переведен текст в очереди Запоздалых ответов

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Не переведены пояснения в очереди Запоздалых ответов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: схожий вопрос [Нет перевода описания для "Выглядит нормально" в запоздалых ответах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12045/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)